# Why are permissions denied writing this file from R?

Tags: r, permissions

I am trying to export some data from R to .csv. It was working yesterday but today I got this error message:

```
Error in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) : 
  cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) :
  cannot open file 'C:/Users/cgarf/Documents/OTL_Model': Permission denied
```

I recently changed java versions. I'm not sure if that could be causing the issue or if I'm missing something

Comment: Please check the folder permissions in properties

Comment: Permissions are handled by your operating system, not R. So this really isn't an R issue. Likely you cannot write to that folder from any application with your current user account.

Answer (score 1):

That error is often because you are trying to write a *file* to a *directory*.

```r
file.exists("quux")
# [1] FALSE
dir.create("quux")
file.exists("quux")
# [1] TRUE
dir.exists("quux")
# [1] TRUE
write.table(mtcars, "quux")
# Warning in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) :
#   cannot open file 'quux': Permission denied
# Error in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) : 
#   cannot open the connection
```

BTW, in case it helps you narrow down *where* the directory is being used (instead of a filename), I just `grep`ed R source (base libraries) and found exactly two instances of `ifelse(append, "a", "w")`:

- [line 28 of `base/R/cat.R`](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/5b2f6e4d8bcaaa354074c40f2685198b929dffcc/src/library/base/R/cat.R#L28); and
- [lines 108-109 of `utils/R/write.table.R`](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/5b2f6e4d8bcaaa354074c40f2685198b929dffcc/src/library/utils/R/write.table.R#L108-L109) (which is also contains `write.csv` and friends).

(Those links are provided "now" as of commit 5b2f6e4.)